# Problem in showing toolbar in PyCharm on Mac

Tags: python, pycharm

[image]Im using PyCharm on MacBook Pro(OS: macOS Mojave). After updating to the new PyCharm version(Version: 2019.1.3), now tool bar is not visible when PyCharm IDE in full screen mode. Is there any solution for this?

Thank you!

Comment: The issue is known, but I struggle to reproduce it reliably https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-23521 Do you have multiple projects opened in different windows?

Comment: thanks for the reply Pavel, at the moment I opened only a one project.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're running in Full Screen mode. On Windows, the key to switch is `F11`, on macOS it's `N/A` according to here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/ide-viewing-modes.html?section=Windows%20or%20Linux

I think that's a documentation error, but I'm sure you can find the appropriate key somewhere in the settings.

You indicated you were indeed running full screen, but the toolbar never displays in full screen, for any project, while it does display in non-full screen. Submitting a bug report here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FPY (with screen shot and good info on your setup) is likely to quickly get you more information - or the confirmation that this is a bug and hopefully a quick fix.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Grismar, but the issue here is it worked previously. but after the update now it not showing any tools when IDE on full screen.

Comment: Ah, I apologise - I only now noticed that you do actually have the toolbar there - in fact you can just see the bottom of the run configuration selection box, but the rest appears to be covered or missing somehow. Does the toolbar render correctly when you're not in full screen? Also, does this happen for all projects, or have you only tried with a specific project open?

Comment: yes it's render correctly in normal screen and also this happened for all the projects

Comment: I would recommend submitting a bug report here https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FPY as this isn't normal behaviour, so it's unlikely an answer on SO will be of much help.

Comment: yes grismar, I'm having the same idea right now. By the way thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

- To exit the full screen mode, choose View | Exit Full Screen on the main menu.The main toolbar contains buttons that duplicate the essential commands for quicker access.
- By default, the main toolbar is hidden. To display it, select View | Toolbar on the main menu.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the quick reply people. today I updated PyCharm to it's newest version(2019.2) and this bug wasn't there.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue on my mac, when projects are opened in fullscreen (at startup) the topbar is "cutted away". You can see that there still is a small line where the run configuration is, so it's not on purpose. What I usually do is leaving fullscreen and reentering it, the issue is fixed.

I am positive the issue is related to fullscreen startup of the IDE.